# Where can I download JSR 166 for Java 8?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, jsr166

e.g. when I look for Lambda specifications, on JCP I do see JSR 335 I can download it as a bunch of HTML and I can go through it.

Is there a similar document for JSR 166.

I tried scraping through [Concurrency Interest group](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/) but beyond the code I couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=166

Comment: thank you, but sorry as I mentioned I did go to that link which led me to  CIG  it is circular, even the community project link points JAVA 5.

Comment: The final draft can be accessed here: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/concurrency-1.0-pfd-spec-oth-JSpec/ I don'T see a circular link here.

Comment: It seems I am not too bright today. I have been clicking on the wrong link. this is hardly a question :D

Comment: I will take that back, I went through the specs, it does point to JSR 166 but for java 1.5(Java 5) which is what I was getting too.

Comment: Are you sure it got changed in java8 ?

Comment: Do expect something crucial, compared to what you can find when looking for `java.util.concurrent` and its sub-packages in [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)?

Comment: Sirko, I think so have a look at CompletableFuture.java.  @Holger when I read the JMS specification or the JSR 335, there were more details around the design and implementation. I am trying to grok the why, not how. If you guys think this is not a valid query for SO let me know.

Comment: The JSR166 has been finished with the release of Java 5, so when you look for JSR166 papers, they have to point to Java 5. When you looked at the [Concurrency Interest group](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/), you already noticed the “JSR166 maintenance updates” and “Repository jsr166-4jdk8” sections, but of course, they are about code/classes. Any plans to change the Java Memory Model would require a new JSR or JEP, like `JEP 188`, for example.

Comment: @holger this makes more sense so in this case, the code with comments and the archives are the best way forward?